# QThread::sleep not work correctly when system time is changed

Tags: c++, qt

Please help me solve this problem.

I create an QT application has a QThread. In run function, use QThread::sleep in while(1) loop. I put qDebug before call sleep. When i run the program. the 'sleep' log will print out every 1 second. 
After that, i change system time by command timedatectl set-time '2015-11-23 08:10:40'.
Now, 'sleep' log is not print out anymore!

```
void TestThread::run()
{
    while (1) {
        qDebug() << "sleep";
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That sounds surprising. Out of curiosity: does thread print again if you set the time back to today (after setting it to the past)?

Comment: Yes! It print again. So surprising!

Comment: fwiw, different lib, similar problem: https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/6787

Comment: I remember that Glib provided `sleep_for()` and `sleep_until()`. One of them caused as trouble in Windows (unfortunately I forgot which of them). May be, the implementation is broken for your system. What is your OS?

Comment: I run the application on Linux Apalis-IMX6 version 2.7 Toradex  Armv7l Release Ver. 4.1.44-2.7.4+gb1555bf. Use qt4.8.6

Comment: I just had a look into [woboq.org](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/). Parts of the `QThread` implementation are separated into [qthread_unix.cpp](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qthread_unix.cpp.html) and [qthead_win.cpp](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qthread_win.cpp.html). The Windows version just calls [`Sleep()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx) (which takes milli-seconds).

Comment: Btw. I just learnt that `QThread::usleep()` is rather worthless in Windows as it calls `Sleep()` as well with duration divided by 1000. :-)

Comment: A co-laborator just told me that the similar boost problems occur in Linux if not using a monotonic clock...

Comment: The Unix version of `QThread::sleep()` calls [`qt_nanosleep()`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qelapsedtimer_unix.cpp.html#_Z12qt_nanosleep8timespec) which in turn calls [`nanosleep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html). Now, the exciting part: _POSIX.1 specifies that nanosleep() should measure time against the CLOCK_REALTIME clock.  However, Linux measures the time using the CLOCK_MONOTONIC clock._ So, what? According to Posix, your observation would make sense but Linux is explicitly excluded. Is this a special issue on your system?

Comment: May be, it could be worth to research the `nanosleep()` on your specific OS a little bit deeper. (I've to admit that I'm developing on Windows only for a lot of years (although I try to do portable code). Before I was using Linux and Irix but that's long ago...)

Comment: How about to use `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` instead?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have tested on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit. The problem is not occur. The debug log is printed even though i reset date time! So that, this is a special issue on my target system (apalis imx6). In addition, i use sleep function in unistd.h. The problem is not occur!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating the source code, i found that the QThread::sleep has implementation:

```
void QThread::sleep(unsigned long secs)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
    struct timespec ti;
    ti.tv_sec = tv.tv_sec + secs;
    ti.tv_nsec = (tv.tv_usec * 1000);
    thread_sleep(&ti);
}

static void thread_sleep(struct timespec *ti)
{
    pthread_mutex_t mtx;
    pthread_cond_t cnd;

    pthread_mutex_init(&mtx, 0);
    pthread_cond_init(&cnd, 0);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    (void) pthread_cond_timedwait(&cnd, &mtx, ti);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

    pthread_cond_destroy(&cnd);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mtx);
}
```

folow this thread https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_timedwait . If the Clock Selection option is supported, the condition variable shall have a clock attribute which specifies the clock that shall be used to measure the time specified by the abstime argument. When such timeouts occur, pthread_cond_timedwait() shall nonetheless release and re-acquire the mutex referenced by mutex. The pthread_cond_timedwait() function is also a cancellation point.

So that, If i change system to the pass, the sleep function will sleep until meet >= the system time begin sleep + sleep period.

Answer (score 0):

Drawn from your experience QThread::sleep is not implemented against some steady clock, therefore moving backwards in time does not work like you expect.

So, the question is: what do you want? A sleep-functionality which is tamper-resistant against time-changes?
Then implement yourself some function in your derived QThread-class, which saves the current time-point as http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock and then checks against that. If enough second(s) have passed since the last call. Of course, this is active waiting and should be refined by passing the control instead of doing another cycle.

Comment: Another hint: I've just seen`void QThread::yieldCurrentThread()`, which could be used exactly to hand over the control.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my project, i want to create a thread that strobe watchdog every 900 ms (watchdog timer set to 1 s). User can change system time. And system will go to reboot because the thread is hang as above. I work around by use sleep function in unistd.h, it work fine. But, my boss require the explain bout why QThread::sleep not work.